# Is there an one-line python code to replace this nested loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

variables:

```
rs = {
    'results': [
        {'addresses': [{'State': 'NY'}, {'State': 'IL'}]},
        {'addresses': [{'State': 'NJ'}, {'State': 'IL'}]}
    ]
}
```

I want to get a list of states for each member of results. Currently I used the following code:

```
for y in rs['results']:
    for x in y['addresses']:
        phy_states.append(x['state'])
```

I want something like:

```
phy_states = [x['state'] for x in y['addresses'] for y in rs['results']]
```

But I don't know how to do. The one line code above does not work because local variable y was referenced before assignment.

Comment: `[x['state'] for y in rs['results'] for x in y['addresses']]`

Comment: Are repetitions allowed in the list of states?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You almost got it, you just got it the other way around:

```
phy_states = [x['State'] for y in rs['results'] for x in y['addresses']]
```